# can't load my webpage ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am using ASP.NET MVC5, my routing was working fine until i create new controller Administrator with Action CreateRole. previously i have modified routes in RouteConfig for my Dashboard, as i don't want to take controller name but just Action name. I have tried with Administrator controller but i still getting error "The resource cannot be found."

many thanks in advance

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //======In order to use only Action Title in URL======//

        //---Dashboard Home Route--//
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "Home/{id}",
            new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //**************************Administrator Route***************************//

        routes.MapRoute(
            "CreateRole",
            "CreateRole/{id}",
            new { controller = "Administrator", action = "CreateRole", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //========default routing=======//
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

### Controller

```
 public class AdministratorController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult CreateRole()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh dear! so whats the solution! i want only action names instead of controller/action

Comment: Can you show your controller, please?

Comment: It works for me, try route debugger from Phil Haack ( http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/ ). It's really easy to set up and use (you just need to comment/uncomment one single line in your Global.asax.cs).

Comment: Did you create the view `/Views/Administrator/CreateRole.cshtml` ?

Comment: thanks Roman and everyone... don't know what was wrong! i restarted visual studio and it worked ... plus didn't change anything ... so don't know why it was doing but it fix ...